# TinyMCE is able to update texts but not images, why is this?

Tags: php, mysql, html, css, tinymce

I'm using TinyMCE on one of my sites and I've reached a point where I want to delete the whole site because of my stupid decision to use this editor.

When I'm logged in, everything works like a charm (except for that TinyMCE lives it's own life sometimes), but when I want to update/replace an image it doesn't do anything at all. Everything looks great in the TinyMCE preview editor, but when I save it to the database nothing happens.

Does anyone know what this could be?

Thank you in advance

**EDIT**:

Here's the code TinyMCE is using when I'm editing:

```
<?php
if($isadmin) {?>
<form method="post" action="dump.php?id=2">
<!-- Gets replaced with TinyMCE, remember HTML in a textarea should be encoded -->
<textarea id="elm1" name="elm1" rows="15" cols="80" style="width: 80%">
<?php } ?>
<?php echo $row[1]; ?>
<?php
if($isadmin) {?>

</textarea>

<br />

<input type="submit" name="save" value="Submit" />
<input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" />
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

And here's the code that TinyMCE uses to run:

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_flush ();

require_once ("include/config.php");


if(isset($_SESSION['admin_user']) && isset($_SESSION['admin_password'])){
    $isadmin = true;
}else{
    $isadmin = false;
}

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("Failed to connect");       

mysql_select_db($dbname) or die("cant access");
// id=4 är sidan 4
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM content WHERE id=2") or die("couldn't select        data");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);


?>

<?php
if($isadmin) {?>
<!-- TinyMCE -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="admin/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
    // General options
    mode : "textareas",
    theme : "advanced",
    plugins :     "autolink,lists,spellchecker,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",

    // Theme options
    theme_advanced_buttons1 :     "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
    theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,spellchecker,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,blockquote,pagebreak,|,insertfile,insertimage",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
    theme_advanced_resizing : true,

    // Skin options
    skin : "o2k7",
    skin_variant : "silver",

    // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
    content_css : "css/example.css",

    // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
    template_external_list_url : "js/template_list.js",
    external_link_list_url : "js/link_list.js",
    external_image_list_url : "js/image_list.js",
    media_external_list_url : "js/media_list.js",

    // Replace values for the template plugin
    template_replace_values : {
            username : "Some User",
            staffid : "991234"
    }
});
</script>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not doing any type of filter on your server side script ? Can you paste some of your $_POST data posted by your tinymce editor ?

Comment: Too vague need code... Must...see....code

Comment: It's often the implementation that is faulty and not the software itself. TinyMCE is a fantastic tool and I've been using it for years. "nothing happens", are you sure? Nothing? Can you see the img code in the source or DB, but the image itself isn't appearing?

Comment: @Cristian I don't think there's any filter, I'm using the original script, I think :)

@mcgrailm this is now added =) sorry for that.

@Madmartigan I can't really agree it's fantastic, I've noticed a lot of errors when editing simple text with it. Maybe I'm using it wrong, but I want the guys that's gonna run this site to be able to edit the content and they've got no knowledge of html or coding.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. What happened is that Tiny converted the image path to relative paths. What I did was disable this option in general options in Tiny configuration:

```
relative_urls: false,
remove_script_host: false,
convert_urls: false
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately this didn't work for me :(

I shows the image when I'm replacing it in edit-mode, everything looks perfectly. But when I apply the changes, it changes the image back. The text updates fine though..

Comment: Is it like an insult if I  press "arrow down" on this answer this is not working for me?

Comment: Someone may find this question later, and he might find an answer useful that you did not. [When should you downvote?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2451/why-do-you-cast-downvotes-on-answers)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to init tinyMCE after the document is ready??

```
$(function() {
   tinyMCE.init({
   ...
   });
});
```